# Why isn't my CSS grid using all available space?

Tags: angular, css-grid

I have the following simple layout:

```css
body {
    height: 100%
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 100px;
}

.header{
    background: red;
}

.content{
    background: blue;
}

.footer{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

From what I've read this should give me a header at the top of the viewport, a footer at the bottom of the viewport and a content area that takes up the rest. Instead I'm getting a header and footer that are the expected size and a content area that auto-sizes to fit its content.

Comment: It looks correct. Try changing the height of the body to `height: 100vh;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your body's height needs to be `100vh;` Otherwise the content does not scale to the full height of the window

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> height:100% only works if the parent element height is in px.

So, instead of using

```
.container {
   height: 100%;
}
```

use

```
.container {
   height: 100vh;
}
```

vh and vw are special unit introduced in css3. Read this for better reference https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/

Answer (score -1):

The `height: 100%` rule won't work on the container because the `body` isn't full viewport height, instead, use `min-height` with the viewport height unit.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I found that I also needed to go to the root container in index.html and make its height 100%